# Nodejs twitter api does not return expected token

Tags: node.js, api, httprequest, twitter-oauth, node-request

I am using nodejs to get bearer token i my code looks like

```
var fs = require("fs");
var https = require("https");
var querystring = require("querystring");
var bearer = "cunsomer_key:cunsomer_secret"
var base64ed = new Buffer(bearer).toString("base64");

var options = {
    port: 443,
    hostname: "api.twitter.com",
    path: "/oauth2/token",
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "Basic " + base64ed,
        "Content-Type": "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        "User-Agent": "socialginie"
    },
    key: fs.readFileSync("./testssl.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./testcert.cert"),
}

var req = https.request(options, res => {
    res.on("data", d => {
        console.log(d.toString());
    })
})
req.on("error", e => {
    console.log(e);
});
req.write(querystring.stringify({
    "grant_type": 'client_credentials'
}))
req.end();
```

The expected return from the api is my bearer token and it does so in postman app but here i get the error `{"errors":[{"code":170,"message":"Missing required parameter: grant_type","label":"forbidden_missing_parameter"}]}`

Does anyone have any idea why api server cannot read the grant type

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just a typo. On this line:

```
    "Content-Type": "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
```

you are specifying "Content-Type" as part of the header *value*.

When I use this curl command, sending your invalid Content-Type, I see the same error you do:

```
$ curl --data "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic <credentials-omitted>" -H "Content-Type:" -H "Content-Type: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token
{"errors":[{"code":170,"message":"Missing required parameter: grant_type","label":"forbidden_missing_parameter"}]}
```

If I correct the header, I get a token:

```
$ curl --data "grant_type=client_credentials" -H "Authorization: Basic <credentials-omitted>" -H "Content-Type:" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8" https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token
{"token_type":"bearer","access_token":"<token-omitted>"}
```